# How to get the value from a list which is bigger and the rest of lists elements is also bigger than the defined value?

Tags: python

I have a 2D list Signal that is a list and contains two lists, the first list is the x values of the signaé and the second is the y values. I would like to get the x value when the y value is bigger than 54.7, but if one of the y values is bigger than 54.7, the rest of the y value should also bigger than 54.7.

Here is the code, but it has a bug. How shall I proceed further

```
    #The signal is a list which contains 2 lists
Signal=[[0,2.5,3,5,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],[10,20,30,40,57,53,54.2,53,52,55,57,52,58,70]]
ti=-1

#Create an x values 
x = Signal[0]
#Create an y values
y = Signal[1]
```

I want to get the first value of the x when the y >54.7, and after all the element is bigger.
The desired output would be 17, so the (ti=17)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search the `y` array from right to left. If the first checked value is `< 54.7`, return `None`, since there is no solution. For each consequent value, check if it is `< 54.7` - if it is, keep going, if it is not, return the previously corresponding `x`. If you reach the leftmost element and it is also `< 54.7`, return `x[0]`.

Answer (score -1):

```
signal=[[0,2.5,3,5,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],[10,20,30,40,57,53,54.2,53,52,55,57,52,58,70]]
ti=-1
threshhold = 34.7
y = signal[1]
y_thresholded = np.array(y)-threshhold
y_bool = y_thresholded > 0
y_bool = list(y_bool)[::-1]
your_index = y_bool.index(False)+1
```

Comment: Unsure, but probably ineffective - you perform comparisons and subtractions on the whole array instead of the target suffix only.

Comment: first, all the operation on the array were vectorize by `numpy` then it more than x10 faster. if the array was very large operate sequential is not a efficient either.